# preg_match_all not working when trying to get all characters including whitespace

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match, preg-match-all

Here is my function:

```
function grabstuff()
{
    foreach (glob("../folder/*.php") as $fn) 
    {
        $file = file_get_contents($fn);

        preg_match_all("#\{\('(\w+)'\)}#", $file, $matches);   

        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) 
        {

            $query = ("ALTER TABLE xxxxx ADD COLUMN `$match` LONGTEXT AFTER xxxxx;");

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Err: ".mysql_error());

        }
    }
}
```

And here is what it looks for on the pages:

```
<?/*{('test test')}*/?>
```

It is ignoring this instance where there is a whitespace.  It works well for testtest and test_test.  Not getting any php errors or mysql errors.  Do I need to use `\w+\S` or `\w+\W`?  I tried both of those, even (...) and it still didn't work.  How do I get my above function to recognize any characters within the {('')}, whether they be a normal abc characters or whitespace.  I'm sure this is simple.  I've done research on google and here and wasn't able to find a solution. (There will be multiple instances of {('')} on any given page if that helps).  I've been using this function for a while now, but would like to add the ability to include whitespaces.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
'(\w+)'
```

`\w` is all alphanumeric characters and the underscore - that doesn't include whitespace. Just use a character set:

```
'([\w\s]+)'
```